# date_add and repeat forever

Tags: mysql, datetime, dateadd

I got an alert table for users, in which we have to send alerts to users in user defined intervals like 0 ( only once), 3 months, 6 months, 1 year

So I designed a table like this

```
id   |   user_id    |   alert_date            |  repeat_int
-----+--------------+-------------------------+-------------
12   |    747       |   2013-04-19 00:00:00   |    0
13   |    746       |   2013-03-19 00:00:00   |    1
14   |    745       |   2012-04-19 00:00:00   |    0
15   |    744       |   2013-04-19 00:00:00   |    0
16   |    743       |   2013-05-19 00:00:00   |    0
```

We are sending alert just a day before "alert_date"

With the following query I can fetch the data

```
SELECT al.id,
       al.user_id,
       al.alert_date,
       al.repeat_int AS repunit
FROM alerts AS al
WHERE DATE_ADD(alert_date,INTERVAL repeat_int MONTH)=date_add(CURRENT_DATE,INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  OR date(al.alert_date)=date_add(CURRENT_DATE,INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Its working file but my real problem is

The repeat will only works once, we need it repeat every interval

ie. If alert date is 2012-03-14 and repeat_int is 0   - Need to work only once
but if alert date is 2012-03-14 and repeat_int is 1   - Need to work in every 14th from 2012-03-14

and if the alert date is 2012-03-14 and repeat_int is 3   - Need to work in every three month's 14. ie alert on 2012-03-14, 2012-06-14, 2012-09-14 etc...

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: What should happen at the end of February if alert_date is 2013-01-31 and repeat_int it 1?

Comment: Then it will be 2013-02-28 . the query returning like this .. its ok.. but any idea about repeat for ever in all months ?

Comment: do you update the alert_date once it is determined it is due for alert? Because in that case it would be much easier to do the query otherwise it would be much more complicated one?

Comment: ok... thanks thirdy ... If I added a new column in DB such as next_alert_date" and update that field once the alert has been send. Then it will be easy to query... Is that the professional way ?

Comment: the query would be much easier if say you have an added field like next_alert_date so every time alert_date has come then it would be updated. so you're query would be simply comparing next day's date against the next alert date. @pilcrow query by the way it looks the one that could solve your problem. But I am just looking on easy maintainability side.

Answer (score 2):

## Update

The OP has changed his schema in response to comments, so the query is essentially:

```
SELECT *
  FROM alerts
 WHERE CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY = COALESCE(next_alert_date, alert_date);
```

This handles "next_alert_date" being NULL on the very first run.

## Original answer

For the original schema:

```
SELECT *
  FROM alerts
  JOIN (SELECT CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY AS tomorrow) d
 WHERE -- We want to alert if
       --  1. Tomorrow is the alert_date
       tomorrow = alert_date
       OR
       --
       --  2. Tomorrow is "repeat_int" months removed from alert_date, falling on
       --     the same day of the month or on the end of the month if the original
       --     alert_date day of month is later in the month than is possible for us
       --     now.  E.g., 2013-01-31 repeated monthly is adjusted to 2013-02-28.
       (
         PERIOD_DIFF(DATE_FORMAT(tomorrow, '%Y%m'), DATE_FORMAT(alert_date, '%Y%m'))
           MOD repeat_int = 0
         AND
         -- Make sure we are at the same day of the month
         ( (DAYOFMONTH(tomorrow) = DAYOFMONTH(alert_date)
          OR
         -- Or, if the day of the alert is beyond the last day of our month,
         -- that we are at the end of our month.
           (LAST_DAY(alert_date) > LAST_DAY(tomorrow)
              AND
            DAYOFMONTH(tomorrow) = LAST_DAY(tomorrow)) )
        );
```